# ruby on rails i18n and number_to_currency negative values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I am using number_to_currency for displaying amount of money, and I have problem with negative values. My hr.yml looks like this:

```
 number:
    currency:
      format:
        format: "%n %u"
        separator: ","
        delimiter: "."      
        unit: "KN"
```

and normal numbers looks ok. For example for 212 I got 212,50 KN which is correct.
But for -212 I got -KN212,50 which is wrong.
I cant find solution anywhere. What have I done wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a negative format in your number_to_currency call :

```
number_to_currency(1.99, :negative_format => '- %n %u')
```

Unless I'm mistaken, there doesn't seem to be a way to store this format in your YAML file unfortunately : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c70135807ed786e6c9e18a35cc83ac6007450ca2/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb#L123

Comment: might be worth opening an issue for this

Answer (score 6):

Just put this line into your `config/locales/your-locale.yml` file:

```
  number:
    currency:
      format:
        negative_format: '-%n %u'
```

and change it so it fits your needs.

Tested in a Rails 3.1.6 app.